# Store Terraform "data consul_keys ..." as file?

Tags: terraform, consul

In a base.tf file I have:

```
data "consul_keys" "project_emails"{
  datacenter = "mine1"
  key {
    name = "notification_list"
    path = "project/notification_email_list"
  }
}
```

I would like to use these consul variables in my python code.
The way I'm thinking about this is by outputting this to a file.  (so not just another terraform file using the `"${project_emails.notification_list.construct}"` with either version 11 or 12.).

How would I save all these keys to a file to access the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general mechanism for exporting data from a Terraform configuration is [Output Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html).

You can define an output value that passes out the value read from Consul like this:

```
output "project_emails" {
  value = data.consul_keys.project_emails.var.notification_list
}
```

After you've run `terraform apply` to perform the operations in your configuration, you can use [the `terraform output` command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/output.html) to retrieve the output values from the root module. Because you want to read it from another program, you'll probably want to retrieve the outputs in JSON format:

```
terraform output -json
```

You can either arrange for your program to run that command itself, or redirect the output from that command to a static file on disk first and then have your program read that file.

---

The above assumes that the Python code you mention will run as part of your provisioning process on the same machine where you run Terraform. If instead you are asking about access to those settings from software running on a virtual machine provisioned by Terraform, you could use the mechanism provided by your cloud platform to pass user data to your instance. The details of that vary by provider.

For long-lived applications that consume data from Consul, a more common solution is to run [`consul-template`](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template) on your virtual server and have it access Consul directly. An advantage of this approach is that if the data changes in Consul then `consul-template` can recognize that and update the template file immediately, restarting your program if necessary. Terraform can only read from Consul at the time you run `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`, so it cannot react automatically to changes like `consul-template` can.